# Moving to a another Method

Tags: java, string, methods

once again I need help about java programming..
I'm trying to make a method that's answerable by yes/no.. but It seems that I'm getting an error: "Illegal start of expression" and "error ";" expected"

if the user input Yes/yes, it will move to the method MainProgram
if the user input No, it will print goodbye and will exit
and if the user input aside from Yes/No it will ask again until the condition is satisfied

please help I really need this.. and yes it's school related. This is actually half of the program, tell me if you need the whole program.. THANKS!

```
import java.io.*;

public class Testing{
    public static void main (String args[])throws IOException{

    String p;
    final String proc="Yes";
    final String decl="No";

        System.out.print("Do you want to proceed? - Yes/No");
        p=inpt.readLine();

        for(int i=1; i<=1; i++){
           if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(proc)){
            MainProgram();
           } else if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(decl)){
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
           } else
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.out.println();
            i=i-1;
            continue;
           }

        public void MainProgram(){
            System.out.println("How many sets of students' grades would you like to record?");
            System.out.print("Answer: ");
            rec = Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: This link will help you in the future, if not now http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=31

Comment: When you ask a question about Java programming you definitely should add [java] tag.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that..

Answer (score 0):

Are you just missing a closing {

Try this.

```
for(int i=1; i<=1; i++)
{
if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(proc))
{
    MainProgram();
} 
else if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(decl)) 
{
System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    System.exit(0);
} 
else {
    System.out.println("Wrong Input");
    System.out.println();
    i=i-1;
    continue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your method `MainProgram()` outside of `main()`.

You cannot define a method inside an other method, at least not in **Java**. :)

Comment: It seems that the method is the one wrong not the loop.. awrgh